# Functional Transformation of a collection of Option<T>

Tags: c#, scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have a collection of `Option<T>` instances and want to transform from `IEnumerable<Option<T>>` to `Option<IEnumerable<T>>`

If **ALL** the options have a value, then I want a `Some<IEnumerable<T>>` with the collected values, if **ANY** of the items in the collection are `None`, then I want a `None<IEnumerable<T>>`

This seems like it would be quite a common functional transformation, but i'm not sure if it exists in mainstream functional libraries, or what it would be called. Seems similar to `FlatMap`, but not quite, as I don't want to just filter out the `None` values.

I could implement it myself, but would like to find out if it exists already as a functional construct. Don't mind what language, C#, Scala, Haskell etc.

Comment: Yes it is a common transformation it is called `sequence` it has the following signature `sequence[F[_] : Traverse, G[_] : Applicative, A](fga: F[G[A]]): G[F[A]]` _(signature provided in **Scala**)_. It seems you need it in **C#**, I do not know if it has it, but at least you already know what to search for.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez! Very interesting. I've done some Scala so will investigate.

Comment: Note, if you end up with that collection of options after a `map`, instead of calling `map` and then `sequence` you can use `traverse` instead. `traverse[F[_] : Traverse, G[_] : Applicative, A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[B]): G[F[B]]` it follows the following equality `sequence(fga) === traverse(fga)(identity)` Thus, you can conclude that `sequence(map(fa)(f)) === traverse(fa)(f)`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the other languages tagged here, but this is also called `sequence` in Haskell - or [sequenceA](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequenceA) for the most general form which works over any `Traversable` holding `Applicative` values.

Comment: Cool, ```sequence``` and ```traverse```. Looks like I have a good starting point for my investigations. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

Language-ext author here, you simply need to call `.Sequence()` to reverse the inner and outer monads:

```
IEnumerable<Option<int>> items = ...;

Option<IEnumerable<int>> result = items.Sequence();
```

It has the exact behaviour you're looking for of returning `None` if any item in the sequence is `None`, and `Some` otherwise.

You can also use `.Traverse(...)` to map the results as you go.

Answer (score 5):

There's more than one 'language family' of functional programming concepts.

In Haskell (and, apparently, Scala) this is called `sequence` and is part of an abstraction or type class called [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Traversable.html); `sequence` is a special case of a traversal.

Other language famiilies exist, most notably ML. This is the where the term `Option` comes from (which in Haskell is called `Maybe`). While I'm well-versed in F# (which is one ML dialect), I'm not aware that *traverse/sequence* has an established terminology there.

Answer (score 2):

These language constructs are *not* initially presented in C#; however, there're multiple functional programming libraries out there for such purposes. My choice would be Paul Louth's [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext); the richest FP library I've found for C# so far.

Comment: Yes, i'm using that exact library! My question still stands, is there an existing named method in the language-ext library which does this transformation?

Comment: I cannot tell for sure; but these transformations, I guess, could easily be implemented using `System.Linq`'s `Select`, `All`, and `Any`.

Comment: It does have `Somes` (https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/OptionExtensions_.htm#Somes%3CA%3E), which is the other way around and could technically be used to implement what you want but inefficiently.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you don't mind the language, I have an example here using F#, which has `Option<T>` out of the box:

```
let chooseAll source =
    let anyNone = source |> Seq.exists Option.isNone
    if anyNone then None else Some source

let s = [Some 1; Some 2; None]
let result1 = s |> chooseAll // None
let s = [Some 4; Some 5]
let result2 = s |> chooseAll // Some {4;5}
```

If you are unfamiliar with F#, `Seq` is a type alias for `IEnumerable<T>`. Here `chooseAll` has the signature `seq<'a option> -> seq<'a> option`, which translating to a C# friendly syntax is `IEnumerable<Option<T>> -> Option<IEnumerable<T>>`.

Comment: I'm fine with F# too :) From your example, you say that from `[Some 1; Some 2; None]` I would end up with `Some {1;2}`, but this is not want I wanted. I would want in this example a `None` as there is at least 1 None in the collection.

Comment: D'oh, pretty important misread! Do you mind if the source is enumerated more than once?

Comment: Well I could implement the method myself without too much issue. I was mainly trying to find out if this was a standard functional construct and would be available in core libraries, and what it's name would be. From the answers above it seems to be `sequence` and `traverse`. Now just need to check if the equivalents are available in F# etc and if I have to write my own implementation, what to name it.

Comment: Ah, I get you. I've updated my answer, but no, I don't know of a standard function to do this, so cannot help with naming (naming is hard by the way!)

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own extension method that relies on available primitives from System.Linq namespace:

```
public static Option<IEnumerable<T>> AllSome<T>(this IEnumerable<Option<T>> input)
            where T : class
            => (input.All(o => o.IsSome)) ?
                new Some<IEnumerable<T>>(input.Select(o => (o as Some<T>).Value)) :
                new None<IEnumerable<T>>() as Option<IEnumerable<T>>;
```

This is based on a throwaway implementation of Option type that I wrote to support this example, feel free to adjust to your flavour of Option:

```
public class Option<T>
    where T: class
{
    protected T value;
    public bool IsSome => value != default(T);
}

public class Some<T> : Option<T>
    where T: class
{
    public Some(T value) => base.value = value;
    public T Value => base.value;
}

public class None<T> : Option<T>
    where T: class
{

}
```

Comment: That looks allsome 

Answer (score 0):

I played with this a bit and it seems like f# fold and foldBack might be of use in this case. Here are some samples:

```
let l1 = [Some 1; Some 2; None]
let l2 = [Some 3; Some 4; Some 5]


let acc (ac: int list option) le = 
    match ac, le with
    | Some ac, Some le -> Some (le::ac)
    | _, _ -> None

//this will reverse the order of elements if all present
let r1 = l1 |> List.fold acc (Some [])
let r2 = l2 |> List.fold acc (Some [])

//the order of elements preserved
let acc2 le (ac: int list option) = acc ac le
let r3 = List.foldBack acc2 l1 (Some [])
let r4 = List.foldBack acc2 l2 (Some [])

//or...
let r3b = l1 |> List.foldBack acc2 <| (Some [])
let r4b = l2 |> List.foldBack acc2 <| (Some [])
```